# Shapeless extensible records with case class type as keys

Tags: scala, shapeless, traits

I have recently discovered Shapeless and I'm wondering whetherit is possible to do the following with it. Let's say I have this sealed trait and case classes:

```
sealed trait T

case class C1() extends T
case class C2() extends T
```

I defined an extensible records of this form:

```
val myRecords = (C1 ->> SomeObj1) :: (C2 ->> SomeObj2) :: HNil
```

However, if I have `val x = C1()`, how can I get `SomeObj1` out of `myRecords`?

I don't want to pattern-match here, and I want to preserve the type information of `SomeObj1` and `SomeObj2`.

Another question is how can I enforce people to extends my `trait T` with another case class to add a corresponding record to `myRecords`.

Comment: I'm not sure you want a record. Polymorphic function seems a better fit: `object foo extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseC1 = at[C1](_ => SomeObj1)
  implicit def caseC2 = at[C2](_ => SomeObj2)
}`

Comment: @Kolmar: Thanks for your reply. At first I thought of a record because I want to have multiple of records at different places (I have multiple sealed traits) and then combine them together. I am not sure how to do it with Polymorphic functions.

Answer (score 0):

You simply use the `apply` method that comes predefined on `myRecords`.

```
import shapeless._ ; import syntax.singleton._ ; import record._

val x: C1 = ...
val myRecords = (x ->> SomeObj1) :: (C2 ->> SomeObj2) :: HNil
val pair = myRecords(x)
```

Comment: Actually not what I want, since there might be multiple objects of type `C1`, I want from each of those to derive `SomeObj1`